# Git file from two different remote origins not getting staged for commit

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-remote

I have a git repository which has two remote origins as follows -

```
origin  https://gitlab.com/harshit.laddha/Angulr.git (fetch)
origin  https://gitlab.com/harshit.laddha/Angulr.git (push)
origin2 https://gitlab.com/harshit.laddha/aarthik.git (fetch)
origin2 https://gitlab.com/harshit.laddha/aarthik.git (push)
```

and I have a GruntFile.js in root directory which was pulled initially from origin1 and then I pulled some other code from origin2 which also had GruntFile.js
Now  this GruntFile.js was automatically merged by git from both the repositories.
But I have tried

```
git add .
```

and then did `git commit -m "message"`
but then also I am seeing the GruntFile.js when I do `git status`

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   GruntFile.js
```

After committing I did `git push origin dashboard`

and then also I am getting the same message on `git status`

I also checked in my remote origin repository the correct merged changes are there in it but still it is showing the same git status message to me.

How can I fix this ?

[UPDATE]
The contents of my .gitattributes are

```
* text eol=lf
```

The git status show some warning messages about some files which is as follows

```
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in client/src/js/app/contact/contact.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in client/src/js/app/note/note.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in client/src/tpl/blocks/header.music.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in client/src/tpl/layout.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in client/src/tpl/music.home.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in client/src/tpl/music.mtv.detail.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in client/src/tpl/music.mtv.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in client/src/tpl/music.playlist.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in client/src/tpl/page_lockme.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in client/src/tpl/page_post.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in client/src/tpl/page_profile.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in client/src/tpl/page_search.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in client/src/tpl/ui_portlet.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in client/src/tpl/ui_timeline.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in client/src/tpl/ui_widgets.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

But the file which I am seeing in the git status is GruntFile.js which is not there in these warnings

Comment: The only case when I've seen these things happening is for files which have an automatic EOL (or some other clean/smudge filter) configured. Can you check if this is your case? `.gitattributes` should have the information.

Comment: @Oblomov the contents of .gitattributes are as follows - * text eol=lf

Comment: Ok, so I suspect that someone at some time in one of the repositories committed the file with the wrong line-endings and now the EOL conversion is going bonkers, can you check what kind of line-endings the on-disk file has?

Comment: I see. Well, coincidentally this is why I hate mixed line-endings repositories ;-).  Still, what are the on-disk line-endings of the problem file? Also, what does `git diff` say? And you have `core.autocrlf` set somewhere? (`git config core.autocrlf` will tell you)

Comment: also I am getting ""  Reloading watch config...

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "Gruntfile.js" deleted. "" in my grunt serve so can it be a problem with my grunt configuration ? also the git config core.autocrlf displays input in my console

Comment: You should type `git diff Gruntfile.js` to check what happen to your grunt file

Comment: GitHub has a [great article](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) on how to deal with line endings. Read through it to see if you can switch your `core.autocrlf` settings and `.gitattributes` to fix the issue.